# React Native installation for Android Emulator on Mac OSX

Tags: react-native

Newbie to React Native

- setting up my MacOSX El Capitan for Android Device Emulator (iPhone Emulator already works for me) with this:
  https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html

I'm running into the following build error on trying to build a generated template React Native app (via rect-native init)

> failed to find target with hash string 'android-23' in: /usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/24.4.1_1/bin

I've tried all of the following, but none of the solutions work:

- within Android Studio:  installed v23 Android Marshmallow SDK
  AND v23 Build Tools (checkbox to expand version numbers)
- within Android Studio; File - Invalidate Caches to wipe .gradle folders under ~ directory for User
- run Android Emulator,from ANDROID STUDIO
- open existing project
- then, choose Tools, Android, Manager AVD to LAUNCH AVD Manager
- tried to build project again
- cd to project directory
  react-native run-android

(BUT SAME ERROR!)

Answer (score 0):

Try to set your ANDROID_HOME variable with the parent directory of platforms and platforms-tools. For example, here I use:

`export ANDROID_HOME=/usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/24.4.1_1/`

Because I installed android-sdk from homebrew.

Other things that I discovered that might lead to this problem:

- you need the proper android tools and SDK installed.
- try to clean the project:

  - cd android && ./gradlew clean

I just did this here and it solved the same problem.